# Within a method m in a class C, isn't this.getClass() always C?

Tags: java

Within a method m in a class C, isn't `this.getClass()` always C?

Comment: Copied from [Java IAQ - Within a method m in a class C, isn't this.getClass() always C?](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#this.class) by Peter Norvig.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it isn't. If there are subclasses.

```
class C {
   Class m() {
      return this.getClass();
   }
}
class D extends C { }
```

and then you can have:

```
C c = new D();
c.m(); // returns D.class
```

Answer (score 8):

Nope:

```
public class C
{
    public void m()
    {
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }
}

public class Child extends C {}
```

Then:

```
new Child().m(); // Prints Child
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    A a = new B();
    a.reportThis();
  }
}
class A { 
  public void reportThis() { 
    System.err.println(this.getClass().getName());
  } 
} 

class B extends A { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword this refers to the object (instance of the class) that is in scope. It means the instance on which the method was called- which in turn means the instances of subclasses as well can be referred to by the keyword 'this'.